# GRUB only detects Windows

Tags: arch-linux, windows, grub2, dual-boot, uefi

On my Arch Linux system, I installed Windows 10 afterwards. Therefore, Windows overwrote the EFI partition and I had to set it up again (because my Arch Linux uses EXT4, so Windows Boot Manager won't work). I managed to install GRUB but for some reason, the Arch installation is not detected; from GRUB, I can only boot into Windows 10.

I tried both `efibootmgr` and `grub-install` (followed by `grub-mkconfig`) and neither of them show results. In my boot startup, both show up as possible selections. The former brings me to GRUB, where I can select to boot Windows; and the latter seems to do nothing at all when I select it.

This is my first time using Arch Linux and my first time using UEFI, so I am at a loss here.

Comment: `grup-update` in my case i lost windows, i had only linux, and this worked for me !

Comment: The case you are describing occurs frequently and seems to be very different from mine. grub-update e.g. didn't do anything for me. I solved it with systemmd now. however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since nobody has yet been able to provide an answer, may I suggest another solution: dump GRUB and use systemd-boot instead. See the [Arch Wiki systemd-boot page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-boot). GRUB is not really needed on UEFI systems, and systemd-boot is much simpler to configure than GRUB.

Comment: Will that work with the dual boot though? According to [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dual_boot_with_Windows#Using_a_Linux_boot_loader), GRUB and Syslinux are my only options.

Comment: Yes, it will work. The link you provided has the caption "BIOS systems", in the document "BIOS" is the opposite of "UEFI".

Comment: While not exactly answering my question, this solved my problem nice and easy, so I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks.